# Some material icon doesn't show in production

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I don't know why but only in production some material icon doesn't appear, as you can see from the image the first icon is missing:

[image]

here's the code:

```
 <mat-nav-list>
   <a mat-list-item routerLink="/dashboard" matTooltip="dashboard">
     <mat-icon matListIcon>bar_chart</mat-icon>
   </a>
   <a mat-list-item (click)="routeToContacts()" matTooltip="contacts">
     <mat-icon matListIcon>people</mat-icon>
   </a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to insert style into the project:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

If it did not solve the problem, please try to add the code below in your **style.css (or style.scss)** :

```
md-icon{
  font-family: 'Material Icons' !important;
}
```

Comment: i thought `ng add @angular/material` will automatically add this css

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SASS and have opacity set to a percentage like

```
mat-icon {
      opacity: 50%;
      padding-right: 0.5em;
}
```

The icons might "disappear" in production builds because a SASS rule. The result is your opacity is 0% or 1% in the CSS files produced.

Changing the opacity to a decimal will give you the result you were expecting.

```
mat-icon {
      opacity: 0.5;
      padding-right: 0.5em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, the icon `event_repeat` appearad as two wrong icons in production build but worked in development build. The build process changes how fonts are embedded. In my case an old version of the woff2-file was loaded ([v109](https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v109/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNcIhQ8tQ.woff2) instead of the current [v121](https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v121/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNcIhQ8tQ.woff2)). The appropriate css in the folder `node_modules\.cache\angular-build-fonts`, so I deleted `node_modules` and ran `cmp ci`. That fixed this issue.